# Selenium Drag and Drop on invisible location

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to implement Drag and Drop in selenium. This is a new scenario I came up with, the drop location is not visible until I drag the source to drop location and hold it. It looks something like this:
[image]

I tried several things like

Scenario 1:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(curSourceElement).build().perform();
builder.moveToElement(curTargetElement).build().perform();
builder.release(curTargetElement).build().perform();
```

Scenario 2:

```
builder.clickAndHold(curSourceElement).build().perform();
builder.moveToElement(curTargetElement).clickAndHold(curTargetElement).moveByOffset(0,500).release(curTargetElement).build().perform();
```

and a lot of other ways by moving to drop location and by adding waits on it but none of them seem to be working.

Is there any other way of doing the drag and drop when the drop location is invisible.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt would look something like this:

```
Size currentWinSize = driver.Manage().Window.Size;
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize(); //Remove window size as a concern

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(curSourceElement);
builder.moveToElement(curTargetElement).Build().Perform();
sleepResponsibly(2000); //Give handler time to react. After working replace 
                        // sleep with wait on ExpectedConditions
builder.release(curTargetElement).build().perform(); 
driver.Manage().Window.Size = currentWinSize; // Put window size back

public void sleepResponsibly(int timeMillisecond){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(timeMillisecond);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

BTW, I run all my tests with Window.Maximize() but included the step in case you don't.  Also, if the hover event handler pops open a new element to act as the target you would need to wait for that new element to be clickable and then release on that new target.  Only you know how your code was designed.